# Если с помощью ajax передавать json в php, то как в дальнейшем использовать этот json в template Handlebars?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, handlebars

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var order = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "action.php", 
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: order,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.result == "ok"){
                        $('.messages').html("<span style='color: green; background: white'>Сообщение успешно отправлено!</span>"); 
                        $('#user_name').val('');
                        $('#user_email').val('');
                        $('#text_comment').val('');

                        var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#template').html() );
//пытаюсь передать значения через переменную order, но так не передаёт
                            $('.updates').append( template(order) );

                    }else{
                        $('.messages').html(data.result);
                    }

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

из php возвращайте JSON с нужными Вам параметрами.

```
{
  "firstName": "Иван",
  "lastName": "Иванов",
  "message": "Тестовое сообщение"
  "status": true
}
```

И передавайте полученный JSON в Handlebars
`$('.updates').append( template(data) );`